# Setting buttonfield to Right and bottom side (Blackberry)

Tags: blackberry

I want my button to be at the right side and bottom side. How it is possible? Please help me. My code below only displays the button on the right side but not bottom.

```
ButtonField b = new ButtonField("button", Field.FIELD_RIGHT | FIELD_BOTTOM);
VerticalFieldManager vf = new VerticalFieldManager(Field.USE_ALL_WIDTH);
vf.add(b);
add(vf);
```

Answer (score 2):

By default, a `VerticalFieldManager` will only use the smallest amount of vertical space necessary to display all of its children.  So, your button is displaying at the bottom of the manager, but the manager is only as tall as your button.  Also, a `VerticalFieldManager` is intended for top-down display.  Try something like this:

```
HorizontalFieldManager hfm = new HorizontalFieldManager(USE_ALL_HEIGHT | USE_ALL_WIDTH);
VerticalFieldManager vfm = new VerticalFieldManager(USE_ALL_WIDTH | FIELD_BOTTOM);
ButtonField b = new ButtonField("Button", Field.FIELD_RIGHT);
vfm.add(b);
hfm.add(vfm);
add(hfm);
```

Comment: i want to fit in display height not below of that. means no scroll use. thanks for your ans. pls suggest me.

Comment: The basic idea is that you've got to create a container (manager) that will include the bottom of the screen if you want to be able to place a component at the bottom of the screen.  Using the `USE_ALL_HEIGHT` style bit is the way that I have done this.  Another option would be to use `setStatus()` on your screen, but that's really a different idea.

Answer (score 1):

thanks to all. but i got my answer.

```
HorizontalFieldManager hfm = new HorizontalFieldManager(USE_ALL_HEIGHT | USE_ALL_WIDTH) {
    public int getPreferredWidth() {
        return Display.getWidth();
    }

    public int getPreferredHeight() {
        return Display.getHeight();
    }

    protected void sublayout(int maxWidth, int maxHeight) {
        int displayWidth = Display.getWidth();
        int displayHeight = Display.getHeight();

        super.sublayout(displayWidth, displayHeight);
        setExtent( Math.min( Display.getWidth(), getPreferredWidth() ),
                Math.min( Display.getHeight(), getPreferredHeight() ) );
    }
};

VerticalFieldManager vfm = new VerticalFieldManager(USE_ALL_WIDTH | FIELD_RIGHT);
ButtonField b = new ButtonField("Button", Field.FIELD_RIGHT);
vfm.add(b);
hfm.add(vfm);
add(vfm);
```

It's perfect work to me.